# Почему изменяется переменная k с 5 на 7 при работе с указателем?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, структуры, список

При добавлении элемента в список, изменяется переменная k, причём иногда программа отрабатывает правильно k всегда равно пяти. Но по каким-то причинами она становится равной 7, потом 9. В конечном результате должны в массив добавляться слова, но если у них одинаковый хеш, то они добавляются в список.

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
struct Lib
{
    char word[50];
    Lib *next;
};

void Print(Lib **array,int n);
void Search(Lib obj[], int n);
void Push(Lib **array, char s[], int hesh);

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int b = 5, k;
    cout << "Введите количество слов:";
    cin >> k;
    Lib *array = NULL;
    int hesh;
    char s[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < k ; i++)
    {
        hesh = 0;
        cout << "Введите слово:" << endl;
        cin >> s;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(s); j++)
        {
            hesh += (int)s[j] + 3;
        }
        while (hesh > b - 1)
        {
            hesh = hesh - 5;
        }
        cout << hesh << endl;
        Push(&array,s, hesh);
    }
    //Print(&array, b);
    system("pause");
}

void Push(Lib **array, char s[], int hesh) {
    Lib *el = new Lib;
    strcpy_s(el->word, s);
    el->next = *(array+hesh);
    *(array + hesh) = el;
}
```

Comment: Вы серьезно? Переменная `n` упоминается два раза в объявлениях функций, и вы хотите, чтобы кто-то определил, где она изменяется и почему, если вы больше ничего не приводите?

Comment: Ну и где ваша переменная `n`?

Comment: @Harry, Боже, простите. Переменная k. После долгих изменений кода, забыл изменить всё обратно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Lib *array = NULL;
```

После этого

```
 Push(&array,s, hesh);
```

а в ней

```
*(array + hesh) = el;
```

Т.е. вы по сути просто портите стек рядом с `array`, записывая не пойими куда  значение `el` - в том числе, вероятно, и в место в памяти, занимаемое переменной `k`.

Для начала нужно выделить память для `array`, а потом - с учетом того, что в `Print` вы передаете адрес переменной - еще и использовать выражение типа `(*array+hesh)`, а не `(array+hesh)`.

Comment: мало того, еще и неопределенное значение  hesh)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а что значит неопределённое?

Comment: значит то, что вы вводите строку, неизвестно какую строку введете и неизвестно какому числу соответствует каждый символ этой строки, которому вы добавляете 3 и этим числом инициализируете   обьект  hesh

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а разве hesh = 0; - не определение?

Comment: Господи боже мой, это определение, но потом же вы  инициализируете его неопределенным значением